# Ruby: .each iteration not working correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I have this assignment:

```
links: { :default => { :some_key => 'some value' }, :not_default => { :another_key => 'another value' } }
```

Now with the following iteration the div `.divider` gets rendered even if the value it contains equals to 'default':

```
- links.each do |key, value|
    - if key != 'default'
        .divider= key
```

It results in:

```
<div class="divider">default</div>
<div class="divider">not_default</div>
```

That behavior cannot be intended.

Comment: Did you mean to compare to symbol? `if key != :default`?

Comment: @Dogbert is on it. The problem is you're expecting strings and symbols to be the same.

Comment: Woo - that works :-)

Comment: In a lot of ways they actually act the same, that's misleading :)

Comment: They act the same in no one single place. They are drastically different.

Comment: @mudasobwa A lot of times Rails interprets strings and symbols the same

Comment: Rails does a lot of dirty things. You probably mean `HashWithIndifferentAccess`, that allows to mix keys, but even there all the keys are stored internally as strings and while you can `hash[:key]`, `hash.keys.detect { |k| k == :key }` would fail. Strings and symbols are very different and this difference is significant, even in such a beast as Rails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key you have is the Symbol `:default`, not a String, which is why your `if` always evaluates to true. You can fix this by doing `key != :default`.

```
- links.each do |key, value|
  - if key != :default
    .divider= key
```